# How can I get outgoing connections with pfSense as my router?

Tags: network, p2p, ports, connection

- I set up a static DHCP reservation for my node.
- I enabled uPNP and port mapping.

  - and I set an ACL to `allow 18080 192.168.node.ip/32 18080`.
- I even set an outbound NAT static port for the IP, in case that would matter.
- I am not double NAT'ed.

I still can't get outgoing connections.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If uPNP won't cooperate, you can create a port forwarding rule (in Firewall > NAT > Port Forward) for the WAN interface that directs a destination of port 18080 to port 18080 of the internal IP of your node.  This will have the effect of also creating a firewall rule on the WAN interface that allows the traffic arriving at port 18080 to pass through to the internal host/IP of the node.